# IsolatedStorage loses object attributes upon tombstoning

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

I am attempting to code a very simple To-Do List application to try out WP8 programming, but I'm having some trouble with IsolatedStorage.

Background:

- The app only supports one To-Do list for now
- List itemThe To-Do List is an object of type ListItem

What I tried to do:

- Save the ListItem object to IsolatedStorage
- When the user quits and
  reopens the app, the app should retrieve the user's data from IsolatedStorage.

Right now, I am able to retrieve the right data while the app is running. When the user quits the app and returns to it, the data is all gone. Can someone help me find out what went wrong?

The main code block for the app:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor

    ListItem toDoList1 = new ListItem();

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ToDoList.ItemsSource = toDoList1.getObjList();

        var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Loading file... rows: {0}", settings.Count());

        if (settings.Contains("myList"))
        {
            ListItem check;
            settings.TryGetValue<ListItem>("myList", out check);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Retrieved number of rows at load: {0}.", check.countRows());

        }
        else
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("File does not exist");

        }

    }

    private void add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        String myInput = input.Text;

        toDoList1.addItem(myInput);

        input.Text = "";

        save();
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int selected = ToDoList.SelectedIndex;

        toDoList1.removeItem(selected);

        save();

    }

    public void save()
    {
        var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
        settings.Remove("myList");
        settings.Add("myList", toDoList1);

        int rows = toDoList1.countRows();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Number of rows at save: {0}", rows);

        ListItem check;
        settings.TryGetValue<ListItem>("myList", out check);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Retrieved number of rows at save: {0}", check.countRows());

    }


}
```

ListItem Class:

```
namespace PhoneApp6
{
public class ListItem
{

    private ObservableCollection<String> objList = new ObservableCollection<String>();

    public ObservableCollection<String> getObjList()
    {
        return objList;
    }

    public void setObjList(ObservableCollection<String> x)
    {
        objList = x;
    }

    public void addItem(String x)
    {
        objList.Add(x);

    }

    public void removeItem(int x)
    {
        objList.RemoveAt(x);
    }

    public int countRows()
    {
        return objList.Count();
    }


}
}
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Call the [IsolatedStorageSettings.Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings.save%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) method

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I tried adding 'settings.Save();' right after 'settings.Add("myList", toDoList1)'. However, the object attributes still fail to get saved.